# If I did MAC filtering whitelist, what will happen with devices that weren’t add to list?

Tags: network, wifi, router, mac-address, mac-spoofing

In my home WIFI router, I set MAC filtering for me and my family’s devices (about 6 devices).

1. If some devices that weren’t in my MAC filtering whitelist, and they know my WIFI password and try to connect to my home WiFi network, what will happen to them? Will they get IP from DHCP in my router?
2. About MAC spoofing, if some devices in my whitelist were MAC spoofed, what will happen if legitimate devices connect to my home WIFI network same time as MAC spoofed devices?

Answer (score 1):

If you have whitelisted certain Mac addresses and blocked everything else, for a device to connect to your network it will need to match two things: the preshared key or password, and the physical Mac address whitelisted on the Mac address table on your router. Anything else will be dropped including devices with spoofed Mac addresses.

Comment: Devices with spoofed addresses won't be dropped if they are spoofing devices on the whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

MAC address filtering could be applied at a few different layers:

- Blocking the filtered devices at the 802.11 level to prevent it from even connecting to the network
- Blocking the filtered devices with a layer 2 or layer 3 firewall. The device can connect and get an IP address, but its traffic will not be forwarded by the router.

Which one might depend on the particular functionality of your router.

> About MAC spoofing, if some devices in my whitelist were MAC spoofed, what will happen if legitimate devices connect to my home WIFI network same time as MAC spoofed devices?

Both devices would likely experience unreliable/intermittent access.